# Rails validates with checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I need some help with my Rails validates. I need to validate that one field is filled out if another field has a certain value. The code is below.

If license has extended selected then the extended license type needs to be filled in. It isn't working, when I fill the form out and select extended and don't check anything for extended_license_type, it validates fine and I get no error message.

License field is a drop down and extended_license_type is a set of checkboxes.

```
  validates :license, presence: true
  validates :extended_license_type, presence: true, :if => :license_extended?

private
    def license_extended?
      license == 'extended'
    end
```

Here is my set of checkboxes for the form. Perhaps my issue is with them and not with the validates. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

```
    <%= f.check_box :extended_license_type, {}, "ur" %>
    <%= f.label :extended_license_type, "Unlimited Reproduction" %>
    <%= f.check_box :extended_license_type, {}, "ms" %>
    <%= f.label :extended_license_type, "Multi-User/Seat" %>
    <%= f.check_box :extended_license_type, {}, "pr" %>
    <%= f.label :extended_license_type, "Product for Resale" %>
    <%= f.check_box :extended_license_type, {}, "ers" %>
    <%= f.label :extended_license_type, "Product for Electronic Resale" %>
    <%= f.check_box :extended_license_type, {}, "ed" %>
    <%= f.label :extended_license_type, "Product for Electronic Distribution" %>
    <%= f.check_box :extended_license_type, {}, "ep" %>
    <%= f.label :extended_license_type, "Extended Legal Protection" %>
```

Here is my drop down for the license field.

```
<%= f.select :license, [["Standard", "standard"], ["Extended", "extended"]] %>
```

Comment: I noticed that it is passing back a '0' for the extended_license_type so my validates is working. I need to make the validates check that it isn't '0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validates was working just fine. It was passing '0' back for extended_license_type and that validates since I was only checking for the presence of that field.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
validates_presence_of :extended_license_type, :if => :license_extended?
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess add a `colon` before the license in `private`,

```
private
    def license_extended?
      :license == 'extended'
    end

validates_presence_of :extended_license_type, :if => :license_extended?
```

(or)

```
validates :extended_license_type, :presence => true, :if => :license?
```